# Plotting a decision boundary python ( give a good idea of how contourf matplotlib function works )

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning, neural-network

This can be considered mostly as a duplicate of another thread, but it's meant to a be granular level explanation intended question.

In Machine Learning algorithms (let's consider a perceptron), I am having set of data points, which spans 2 features. So the input features are of the form

```
## Assume classifier has already been trained for simplicity
X = [[a1,b1] , [a2,b2] , .... , [an,bn]]

x1_min, x1_max = X[:, 0].min() - 1, X[:, 0].max() + 1
x2_min, x2_max = X[:, 1].min() - 1, X[:, 1].max() + 1
xx1, xx2 = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x1_min, x1_max, resolution),
                   np.arange(x2_min, x2_max, resolution))

Z = classifier.net_input(np.array([xx1.ravel(), xx2.ravel()]).T)

### Here Z is set of prediction which has values +1 or -1 , for the data points in X
Z = Z.reshape(xx1.shape).

# plot class samples

for idx, cl in enumerate(np.unique(y)):
     plt.scatter(x=X[y == cl, 0], y=X[y == cl, 1],
            alpha=0.8, c=cmap(idx),
            marker=markers[idx], label=cl)
plt.show()
```

As of now everything is fine. My real problem is what the following function do or how it works, when we are passing the data points `xx1` and `xx2` along with predicted value `Z` (which is nothing but a bunch of +1 and -1). I am not familiar with contours. Can any one explain how we are getting that decision boundary through the `contourf` function?

```
plt.contourf(xx1, xx2, Z, alpha=0.4, cmap=cmap)
```

[image]

This is the generated decision boundary separating two classes. Can someone explain what is happening inside the `countourf` function or how we derive this decision boundary with `xx1`, `xx2` and `Z` (bunch of +1 and -1)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In

```
xx1, xx2 = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x1_min, x1_max, resolution),
                       np.arange(x2_min, x2_max, resolution))
```

you create a grid that spans the range of the data and has a given resolution. This grid has no connection to the actual data points, it is just a grid laid over the input space.

Then, in

```
Z = classifier.net_input(np.array([xx1.ravel(), xx2.ravel()]).T)
Z = Z.reshape(xx1.shape)
```

you let the classifier compute the output for each point of the grid. This gives the +1 or -1 for each point on the grid and also reshapes the output array so that it matches the shape of the gird.

Finally, there is the `contourf` function. [Here](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.contourf) is its documentation. What `contourf` basically does is that it takes a 3-D surface specified by a grid (i.e. a bunch of X-Y points along with the Z-value of these points) and plots this surface by displaying its contours. A contour is a line where the surface has the same value. Since the `Z` array contains only +1s and -1s, the only real contour is at the points "between" the +1s and -1s, i.e. the decision boundary.

**In a nutshell**, the decision boundary is extracted by finely sampling the feature space and plotting the output value for each sample. The boundary then comes out implicitly as the output values vary across the feature space.